# is there a way to export classification model from Orange to be used in Earth engine API?

Tags: orange

I used a pest infestation class sample point data and Sentinel 2 reflectance image for each points to build a classification model by using Orange Data Mining. I would like to use the model to classify the images from earth engine API in python. is it possible? anyone ever done it before?

i tried to export model as pickle from the orange, but i failed to load it in earth engine (i used API in google colab).
i expect the classification done for each of the Sentinel 2 Image loaded from EE